# How to connect custom UIView in interface builder using storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard, custom-view

I want to use an `F3BarGauge` ( http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/f3bargauge ) in my iOS app and I want to use a .storyboard for my UI design.

I managed to achieve this programmatically by writing code into the view controller's `loadView:` method, which creates the instance of the `F3BarGauge` and adds it to the view via `[self.view addSubview:myBarGauge];` .

However, now I can't see the `F3BarGauge` at all in the preview in Interface Builder and therefor I also can't adjust the size or position of the `F3BarGauge` from there. I can only do this in the code. Moreover, I think it is confusing for my colleagues if I create parts of the UI elements automatically through the .storyboard and some in my own code.

I would like to find a solution for both of these disadvantages.
It is not important for me to see the actual custom UI element's content (in this case the `F3BarGauge`) in Interface Builder. If the frame of the `F3BarGauge`'s area is displayed in Interface Builder and I can move and resize it, then I'm happy with the solution.

I do not have an example for this approach, because the example from the author of the `F3BarGauge` uses a .xib file and not a .storyboard.

I'm relatively new to iOS programming and Xcode / Interface Builder. Maybe there is a better way to achieve what I want than how I imagine my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to see the F3BarGauge in IB, but you can add a UIView as a subview of your main view in IB, size and position it as you like, and then in code, add the F3BarGauge to the subview.

After Edit: Actually, after looking at the author's demo project, you can see it in IB. Just copy and paste his view from the demo project into a view controller (after deleting the default view first).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Meanwhile I also found a tutorial, which explains a good solution from ground up in much detail. They add a UIView (called simply "View" in Interface Builder) and then change the connected class to the custom subclass of UIView that you want (F3BarGauge in my case). Click on  http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view and then scroll down to "Using the 5 Star Rating View" to see the relevant part of the tutorial.